# Refreshing a JWT Access Token using JWT Refresh Tokens and NestJS

Tags: jwt, nestjs, passport.js, refresh-token, auth-guard

I am setting up auth using access tokens and refresh tokens. I am largely there, but I am having trouble understanding how to refresh the access token. From what I have seen from here and other resources, most people seem to set up route handlers to refresh the token like so:

```js
@UseGuards(JwtRefreshGuard)
@Get('/refresh')
refresh(@GetUser() user: User) {
  return this.authService.getAccessToken(user.username);
```

I am using a custom guard using a passport strategy to validate the refresh token:

```js
async validate(request: Request, payload: JwtPayload) {
  const { username } = payload;
  const refreshToken = request.cookies?.Refresh;
  return this.userService.getUserIfRefreshTokenMatches(
    refreshToken,
    username,
  );
```

What I am not understanding is how to implement making a request to this handler without interrupting the app user's normal operations, and how to check if this handler needs to be called when an access token expires.

Answer (score 0):

> how to check if this handler needs to be called when an access token expires.

When you make a call with jwt token from the client to the server if it is expired(which is the case that we use refresh token) with jsonwebtoken npm package we can send a callback to the client with the message "Jwt expired"(since you are validating the jwt you can identify if it an expired token). Then the client can send another request to your `/refresh` endpoint on the server requesting a new jwt token. Then you can send the new jwt token from the server to the client and the client can use the newly created jwt to send requests to the protected routes on the server.

Comment: I thought he understand that. But how to implement it ? Plz share your code for implementing that refresh token handler without interrupting the user's operations, if no then your answer is more appropriate as a comment

Comment: There is no need for additional implementation. you can use the same function that you used to create the jwt token in the first place when the user is login to the system. The only additional part is that you need to validate the refresh token before issuing a new access token. This can be easily done with an additional field in the user document(MongoDB) such as token_count. After validation called the function that you used to create the access token and send the new jwt.

Comment: You have mentioned what additional part that need to be implemented, that didn't exist in your answer. He is asking How to Implement, not how it works.

Answer (score 0):

On client side you can control access token expires. So, if the access token has 5 minutes of life, and was born 3 minutes ago, then only the access token can be transferred to the backend. But if 10 minutes have passed since the birth of the access token, then the client must first send a refresh token to the backend, and continue to process the current request only after receiving a new access token.